# Spring Config Server - does not refresh properties

Tags: spring-cloud

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigServer
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
     server:
        uri: http://github.com/<myuser>/config
```

When I start application it clones repository to local folder and serves application properties from

```
 http:// localhost:8080/testapp/default
```

Now when I modify file on github and go to

```
 http://localhost:8080/testapp/default
```

I can see it downloads modification as .tmp file but does not merge and keep showing old property values until config server is restarted.

Of course if modification is made to the local repo copy changes take place.

What am I doing wrong? I would like to manage files on github and ConfigServer automatically download changes.

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see any tmp files. Can you explain that in a bit more detail (what happens in the basedir when you load the changes).

Comment: @Dave Syer:  This is how directory looks after repo is cloned    http://screencast.com/t/srVuSVem8Pqu   and this is http://screencast.com/t/bhZaoXwRD how it looks after testapp.yml was modified/committed/pushed into githube repot and I attempted to reload configuration by going to  http://localhost:8080/testapp/default again. I am using Spring Cloud 1.0.0.M2

Comment: Traced the code: it blows up on pull.call(); in JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:188 - org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of merge command. java.io.IOException: Could not delete file C:\<mypath>\target\basedir\testapp.yml.. I noticed however that file is being kept open by java - http://screencast.com/t/wp8qkMmr . Seems like initial clone - keeps file open and subsequent pulls fail?

Comment: Must be a windows problem (I'm not sure anyone tried it before). Do the unit tests pass on windows?

Comment: Unit tests failed on Windows.. all related to "not being to delete file" JGitEnvironmentRepositoryIntegrationTests.init:48, JGitEnvironmentRepositoryTests.init:45. I am going to email log file

Comment: Could not find Spring Cloud on http://jira.spring.io. Here is the link for the maven output mvn test -s .setting.xml: http://bit.ly/1yzwroJ

Comment: We use guthub for issues (not JIRA). Thanks for the investigation.